# .svg file as object in HTML not displayed in Android WebVIew

Tags: android, html, svg, android-webview, embed

My app has a WebView control that is able to load .svg files: when the url is a .svg file it is correctly displayed.

I modified the code not to load directly the .svg file so that I have to call something like

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl,"<html><body><object data='cover.svg'></object></body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8","");
```

- The above mentioned code works with images but not with svg files.
- An HTML file with the HTML parameter string above mentioned as HTML code is correctly displayed in Firefox (under Linux) with its svg object.
- The object is always loaded with a WebView/browser-compatible file.
- I want my code to be able to handle every kind of WebView/browser-compatible file that can be placed in an object.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: @Manjunath Siddappa It doesn't work either, but note that my original goal is to handle every kind of possible object, not only images and svg

Answer (score 3):

This worked with various formats:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl,"<html><body><object onload='event.target.style.minWidth=screen.width;event.target.style.minHeight=screen.height;' data='cover.svg'></object></body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8","");
```

Comment: For someone wondering what to put in baseUrl , In my case it's working with empty string

Answer (score 0):

To add SVG using the object element, write markup such as the following link

http://alistapart.com/article/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii

```
  <object type="image/svg+xml" 
    width="100" height="100" style="float:right" 
    data="http://blog.codedread.com/clipart/apple.svgz">
  <span/></object>
```