# Svg files to display in Android

Tags: c#, android, svg, vector-graphics

I have a large number of svg files (over 1000) that have keyframe animations included in the CSS. Ultimately I want to be able to display these in an android app.

I looked into using android vectordrawable among other solutions but that will only display the image from path data and wont be feasible to try add animations to every file.

I have have also tried converting to png using http://www.codeplex.com/svg in c#, again the png file does not include the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Webview to display your svg.

here is a post that can help [.svg file as object in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589782/3252671)